# Update RavenDB Raven-Clr-Type after moving class to new namespace

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

I need to update the RavenDB `Raven-Clr-Type` after moving multiple classes to a new namespace.

**Example Old Metadata:**

```json
"@metadata": {
    "@collection": "SomeClass",
    "Raven-Clr-Type": "BO.SomeClass, BO"
}
```

**Example New Metadata:**

```json
"@metadata": {
    "@collection": "SomeClass",
    "Raven-Clr-Type": "BO.SubNamespace.SomeClass, BO.SubNamespace"
}
```

One approach I've considered is loading a collection with a `Query`, iterate over the list and `Store` each object individually in the DB. This seems to work fine, but unfortunately, the storing of each object individually is for large collections very inefficient. I've tried to use RavenDB's `Bulk Insert` method as an alternative, but it doesn't appear to update the `Raven-Clr-Type`, just the "data".

The need to update the Raven-Clr-Type after a namespace change is associated with how we query by ID. We perform a strict type check when loading an object by ID, and if the namespace does not match, we return an error.

```cs
using var bulkInsertOperation = Store.BulkInsert(new BulkInsertOptions
{
    SkipOverwriteIfUnchanged = false
});
foreach (var item in list)
{
    bulkInsertOperation.Store(item);
}
```

### My Question:

- What would be the most effective way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send a **Patch operation**, this should work for you:

```
var operation = store
    .Operations.Send(new PatchByQueryOperation(new IndexQuery
    {
        Query = @"from YourCollectionName update
                {                                      
                    this['@metadata']['Raven-Clr-Type'] = 'TheNewNameSpaceYouWant';                                      
                }"
    }));
    
operation.WaitForCompletion();
```

---

There are more examples of **set-based operations** here:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/6.0/csharp/client-api/operations/patching/set-based

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm. I construct my query from a Generic type in the following manner:

`var collection = Store.Conventions.GetCollectionName(typeof(T));`
`var fullName = typeof(T).FullName;`
`var assembly = typeof(T).Assembly.GetName().Name;`
`var query = $"from {collection} update {{ this['@metadata']['Raven-Clr-Type'] = '{fullName}, {assembly}'; }}";`